# How to capture Airodump-ng scan output to CSV that mirrors the output shown in the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, aircrack-ng

I am trying to output the results of Airodump-ng to a CSV file that would mirror what shows when Airodump-ng is run in the terminal.

I've tried using the appropriate options to output to a CSV but the .csv file does not show everything that is shown in the terminal.

Command:

```
sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon -w out --output-format csv
```

Terminal:

```
 CH  8 ][ Elapsed: 6 s ][ 2020-03-09 22:02 ][ display ap+sta                                            

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID                              

 A0:63:91:E3:41:C9  -61       12        2    0  10  405  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  (NETWORK 1)                      
 7C:DB:98:B4:5D:59  -76        3        0    0   5  720  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  (NETWORK 2)                
 34:6B:46:2C:75:96  -77        8        0    0   6  195  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  (NETWORK 3)                
 A4:08:F5:47:27:66  -75        8        0    0  11  195  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  (NETWORK 4)                
 50:6A:03:A8:AC:C4  -86        2        0    0   6  195  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  (NETWORK 5)                 

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe                                    

 (not associated)   C8:3A:6B:3A:18:E5  -59    0 - 6      0        7  (NETWORK 6)                      
 (not associated)   0C:72:D9:50:30:E5  -81    0 - 1      0        5                                           
 (not associated)   E4:F0:42:77:F3:DA  -83    0 - 1      4        3  (NETWORK W)                               
 (not associated)   80:D2:1D:30:B2:3B  -82    0 - 1      1        3  (NETWORK X)                               
 (not associated)   48:D6:D5:64:31:2E  -27    0 - 1     12        8  (NETWORK Y)                                
 (not associated)   80:7D:3A:53:C5:07  -45    0 - 1     15       11  (NETWORK 6)                      
 (not associated)   80:7D:3A:53:BE:70  -40    0 - 1     47        9  (NETWORK 6)                      
 (not associated)   DA:A1:19:20:62:CC  -55    0 - 1      0        1                                           
 (not associated)   DA:A1:19:AC:B7:21  -56    0 - 1      0        1                                           
 (not associated)   DA:A1:19:73:B5:56  -58    0 - 6      0        1                                           
 (not associated)   EC:0E:C4:DC:9F:35  -90    0 - 1      0        1  (NETWORK Z)
```

CSV:

```
BSSID, First time seen, Last time seen, channel, Speed, Privacy, Cipher, Authentication, Power, # beacons, # IV, LAN IP, ID-length, ESSID, Key

Station MAC, First time seen, Last time seen, Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs
A0:56:F3:02:0A:DF, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, -86,        2, 7C:DB:98:B4:5D:59,
02:0F:B5:5F:6B:66, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, -86,        1, A0:63:91:E3:41:C9,
6C:56:97:55:55:31, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:44, -84,        4, 94:62:69:44:2E:D0,
AC:63:BE:FB:E2:BA, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, -84,        1, A0:04:60:05:41:27,
02:0F:B5:6B:0D:19, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, -83,        1, A0:63:91:E3:41:C9,
02:0F:B5:FB:E2:BA, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, -82,        1, A0:63:91:E3:41:C9,
68:DB:F5:41:43:60, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, -79,        1, F8:F5:32:B5:43:B0,
E4:F0:42:77:F3:DA, 2020-03-10 00:29:50, 2020-03-10 00:29:50, -79,        8, (not associated) ,(NETWORK W)
A0:91:69:D2:02:C9, 2020-03-10 00:29:42, 2020-03-10 00:29:53, -73,       30, 7C:DB:98:B4:5D:59,
60:70:C0:3D:5C:C9, 2020-03-10 00:29:50, 2020-03-10 00:29:52, -51,       21, 60:FE:20:55:92:46,
4C:7C:5F:30:2B:2E, 2020-03-10 00:29:44, 2020-03-10 00:29:44, -64,        1, 2C:30:33:FD:A3:A2,
C8:3A:6B:3A:18:E5, 2020-03-10 00:29:40, 2020-03-10 00:29:48, -57,       20, (not associated) ,(NETWORK 6)
48:8D:36:42:16:01, 2020-03-10 00:29:41, 2020-03-10 00:29:41, -54,        1, 60:FE:20:55:92:46,
1C:12:B0:BC:F0:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, 2020-03-10 00:29:52, -54,      135, 60:FE:20:55:92:46,
CE:A5:8F:56:52:DC, 2020-03-10 00:29:46, 2020-03-10 00:29:46, -51,        3, (not associated) ,
80:7D:3A:53:C5:07, 2020-03-10 00:29:41, 2020-03-10 00:29:51, -37,        9, (not associated) ,(NETWORK 6)
80:7D:3A:53:BE:70, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:53, -39,       16, (not associated) ,(NETWORK 6)
64:89:F1:6D:6D:D3, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:39,  -1,        1, 1C:1B:68:D5:AF:B0,
DC:44:B6:B7:E1:59, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:39,  -1,        1, 1C:1B:68:D5:AF:B0,
60:45:BD:36:15:CC, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:53,  -1,        6, AC:3B:77:4A:76:44,
94:0C:98:00:18:FF, 2020-03-10 00:29:44, 2020-03-10 00:29:44,  -1,        1, D4:04:CD:7A:9E:F0,
EA:C0:9A:AE:55:E2, 2020-03-10 00:29:52, 2020-03-10 00:29:52, -88,        1, (not associated) ,
F8:D0:AC:41:48:00, 2020-03-10 00:29:53, 2020-03-10 00:29:53, -85,        1, A4:08:F5:47:27:66,(NETWORK 4)

-10 00:29:41, 2020-03-10 00:29:48, -48,        5, (not associated) ,(NETWORK 6)
64:89:F1:6D:6D:D3, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:39,  -1,        1, 1C:1B:68:D5:AF:B0,
DC:44:B6:B7:E1:59, 2020-03-10 00:29:39, 2020-03-10 00:29:39,  -1,        1, 1C:1B:68:D5:AF:B0,
60:45:BD:36:15:CC, 2020-03-10 00:29:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:43,  -1,        3, AC:3B:77:4A:76:44,
94:0C:98:00:18:FF, 2020-03-10 00:29:44, 2020-03-10 00:29:44,  -1,        1, D4:04:CD:7A:9E:F0,
CE:A5:8F:56:52:DC, 2020-03-10 00:29:46, 2020-03-10 00:29:46, -51,        3, (not associated) ,
1C:12:B0:BC:F0:43, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, -54,        4, 60:FE:20:55:92:46,
02:0F:B5:FB:E2:BA, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, -82,        1, A0:63:91:E3:41:C9,
AC:63:BE:FB:E2:BA, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, 2020-03-10 00:29:47, -84,        1, A0:04:60:05:41:27,
```

As you can see, a lot of the networks in the upper portion of what is seen in the terminal( Networks 1-5) are not present in the csv file.

Is there anything I'm missing in the Airodump-ng command? Any guidance or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. After looking through the man page of Airodump-ng and considering all the options, I decided to use another tool to successfully gather all the significant information I was searching for.

Instead of using Airodump-ng, I decided to use Wash.
Specifically using the -a option to capture information about all networks not just networks with WPS.

For anyone in the future, just use Wash and parse the needed data using | grep, Python, or any other language.